# Remove sorting for columns

Tags: datatables

Trying to turn off sorting for specific columns in my table, but the wrong columns are affected? Can anyone see what I am missing here?

HTML

```
<table id="tableListing" class="table table-striped table-hover">
<thead>
  <tr>
   <th class="no-sort"></th>
   <th>Personnumer</th>
   <th>Namn</th>
   <th>Skapad</th>
   <th class="no-sort"></th>
  </tr>
 </thead>


<tbody>
 <tr>
  <td><a href="member_search.aspx?del=85&fn=&ln=&pn=" onclick="return confirm('Är du SÄKER? All information kommer raderas och kan inte återställas!'); return false;" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">radera</a></td>
  <td>630214-0410</td>
  <td>DEAD3, Test</td>
  <td>2017-07-18 19:07:12</td>
  <td><a href='member_details.aspx?id=85'>info</a></td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
  <td><a href="member_search.aspx?del=86&fn=&ln=&pn=" onclick="return confirm('Är du SÄKER? All information kommer raderas och kan inte återställas!'); return false;" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">radera</a></td>
  <td>650301-4257</td>
  <td>Doe, John</td>
  <td>2017-07-31 22:14:50</td>
  <td><a href='member_details.aspx?id=86'>info</a></td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

JS

```
$("#tableListing").DataTable({           
        "lengthMenu": [[50, 100, 150, 200, 250, -1], [50, 100, 150, 200, 250, "All"]],
        "iDisplayLength": 100,
        "order": [],
        "columnDefs": [{
            "targets": 'no-sort',
            "orderable": false
        }]
    });
```

Much appreciated!

EDIT: Added image of how it turns out. As you can see, the wrong columns are affected.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you want to deactivate sorting for specific columns only, you can do it like this:

```
$('#tableListing').DataTable({
    columnDefs: [
        { "orderable": false, "targets": [ 0, 4 ] }
    ]
});
```

Or you can add a class like "no-sort" to the column header where you want to suppress sorting.

```
<thead>
  <tr>
   <th class="no-sort"></th>
   <th>Personnumer</th>
   <th>Namn</th>
   <th>Skapad</th>
   <th class="no-sort"></th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
```

And then use that in the DataTable definition:

```
$('#tableListing').DataTable({
        columnDefs: [
            { "orderable": false, "targets": 'no-sort' }
        ]
    });
```

Comment: Added image, please have another look? Sorting is restricted, but the wrong columns are affected.

Comment: Looks like the correct columns to me. You wanted to to restrict sorting for the 1st and 5th column. That is exactly what the image shows. Maybe to clarify: the arrows appear to the right of the column that they effect.
I will also update my answer since the "no-sort" class apparently works.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use as for specific columns as

```
$(document).ready(function() {
oTable = jQuery('#tableListing').dataTable( {           
            "bDestroy": true,
            "bAutoWidth": true,  
            "bFilter": true,
            "bSort": true, 
            "aaSorting": [[0]],         
            "aoColumns": [
                { "bSortable": false },
                { "bSortable": true },
                { "bSortable": true },
                { "bSortable": true },
                { "bSortable": true },
                { "bSortable": true },
                { "bSortable": false }
            ]   
        } );
 })
```

You can exclude the column where you do not want sorting as  set bSortable to false.

Comment: Added image, please have another look? Sorting is restricted, but the wrong columns are affected.

Answer (score -1):

Well,In the new version 1.10 of jQuery DataTables you must use ordering option to disable ordering on the entire table:

```
$('#tableListing').DataTable({
    "ordering": false
});
```

Comment: [Nick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3210868/nick) you can see my updated answer..above